# How do I set multiple int's equal to the same number ? Java

Tags: java, initialization

I have the code `int index, r, g, b;` and I want to set all of them equal to a certain number, I don't individually want to write `index = 0; r = 0;`... and so on.

How do I do this in java? 
      `index,r,g,b = 0;` doesn't work for me.

Comment: Do it that way anyway. Chained assignment has all sorts of pitfalls, and initializing each variable separately is much cleaner.

Comment: I agree with @chrylis. If you don't want to do something one way, you should have a good explanation why not, instead of just "I'm too lazy to type out some characters".

Comment: Thanks I'll keep that in mind, I was just very curious

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use this line of code for initializing all the variables at once

```
r = g = b = index = 0;
```

or else initialize when you declare like:

```
int index=0, r=0, g=0, b=0;
```

Answer (score 5):

Initialize all the values, then set the values.

```
int index, r, g, b;
index = r = g = b = 0;
```